# android useful libraries for download file and show photo browser gallery

Tags: android

i'm new on Android. 
I used these libraries for my iOS projects, most useful for simplify some common tasks. 
There are similar counterparts libraries for Android development?

MWPhotoBrowser - https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

SDWebImage - https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

MBProgressHUD - https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

ASIHTTPRequest - http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to display images from server.

What common tasks you intend to do in android??

You can use lazy loading to display images form server. https://github.com/thest1/LazyList.
Uses caching.

You can also try Universal Image Loader. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. Asynchronously loads images. Cache images to sdcard.

To get images from server, you can use AsyncTask. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. If you require long running operation then do not use asynctask.

For long Running background operation use Service. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html.

There is an alternative to AsyncTask called Robospice. https://github.com/octo-online/robospice.

In your case you can use Universal Image Loader to display images form server.

To make http requests you can use Apache HTTP. http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi.
Download the jar add it to your project.

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/downloading-an-image-from-the-server-and-displaying-it-on-screen. Example of using http get request to download image from server

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan, yes my idea it's download file from a web server and load images from internet and cache them for display also if a connection is not available. I'm taking a look at your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: but for display it in a gallery like the native full screen gallery of iOS i need to put them in a HorizontalScrollView so i can swipe troughts the downloaded image?

Comment: you mean to say gridview. then you can use universal image loader. i do not know about ios.

Comment: i'm not read all the information about this, but for have a quickly idea, I do not understand if Robospice managed only download of files or can manage also get or post request from the server and retrieve also the response, for example a value from the server, a text, ...? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. Do you mean loading images like this?

Comment: Yes Raghunandan!! Something like this.

Comment: for that use the library in link 2. For http get request use the same in the last link.